# Pure Python faster than Numpy? can I make this numpy code faster?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to compute the min, max, and mean from a specific list of faces/vertices. I tried to optimize this computing with the use of Numpy but without success.

Here is my test case:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
'''
Module Started 22 févr. 2013
@note: test case comparaison numpy vs python
@author: Python4D/damien
'''

import numpy as np
import time


def Fnumpy(vertices):
  np_vertices=np.array(vertices)
  _x=np_vertices[:,:,0]
  _y=np_vertices[:,:,1]
  _z=np_vertices[:,:,2]
  _min=[np.min(_x),np.min(_y),np.min(_z)]
  _max=[np.max(_x),np.max(_y),np.max(_z)]
  _mean=[np.mean(_x),np.mean(_y),np.mean(_z)]
  return _mean,_max,_min

def Fpython(vertices):
  list_x=[item[0] for sublist in vertices for item in sublist]
  list_y=[item[1] for sublist in vertices for item in sublist]
  list_z=[item[2] for sublist in vertices for item in sublist]
  taille=len(list_x)
  _mean=[sum(list_x)/taille,sum(list_y)/taille,sum(list_z)/taille]
  _max=[max(list_x),max(list_y),max(list_z)]
  _min=[min(list_x),min(list_y),min(list_z)]    
  return _mean,_max,_min

if __name__=="__main__":
  vertices=[[[1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4]]*4]*1000000
  _t=time.clock()
  print ">>NUMPY >>{} for {}s.".format(Fnumpy(vertices),time.clock()-_t)
  _t=time.clock()
  print ">>PYTHON>>{} for {}s.".format(Fpython(vertices),time.clock()-_t)
```

The results are:

*Numpy:*

> ([1.1000000000452519, 2.2000000000905038, 3.3000000001880174], [1.1000000000000001, 2.2000000000000002, 3.2999999999999998], [1.1000000000000001, 2.2000000000000002, 3.2999999999999998]) for **27.327068618s.**

*Python:*

> ([1.100000000045252, 2.200000000090504, 3.3000000001880174], [1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]) for **1.81366938593s.**

Pure Python is 15x faster than Numpy!

Comment: This line is slow `np_vertices=np.array(vertices)` . You're not really timing the min and max functions, you're timing how long it takes to sort out the nested references

Comment: You should edit your question to make what I think is your implied question, "can I make this numpy code faster?", explicit to fend of the close votes.

Comment: By using numpy constructs only (also for building `vertices`), you can speed up your code considerably.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason your `Fnumpy` is slower is that it contains an additional step not done by `Fpython`: the creation of a numpy array in memory. If you move the line `np_verticies=np.array(verticies)` outside of `Fnumpy` and the timed section your results will be very different:

```
>>NUMPY >>([1.1000000000452519, 2.2000000000905038, 3.3000000001880174], [1.1000000000000001, 2.2000000000000002, 3.2999999999999998], [1.1000000000000001, 2.2000000000000002, 3.2999999999999998]) for 0.500802s.
>>PYTHON>>([1.100000000045252, 2.200000000090504, 3.3000000001880174], [1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]) for 2.182239s.
```

You can also speed up the allocation step significantly by providing a datatype hint to numpy when you create it. If you tell Numpy you have an array of floats, then even if you leave the `np.array()` call in the timing loop it will beat the pure python version.

If I change `np_vertices=np.array(vertices)` to `np_vertices=np.array(vertices, dtype=np.float_)` and *keep it in `Fnumpy`*, the `Fnumpy` version will beat `Fpython` even though it has to do a lot more work:

```
>>NUMPY >>([1.1000000000452519, 2.2000000000905038, 3.3000000001880174], [1.1000000000000001, 2.2000000000000002, 3.2999999999999998], [1.1000000000000001, 2.2000000000000002, 3.2999999999999998]) for 1.586066s.
>>PYTHON>>([1.100000000045252, 2.200000000090504, 3.3000000001880174], [1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]) for 2.196787s.
```

Comment: I tried np_vertices=np.array(vertices, dtype=np.float_) or np_vertices=np.array(vertices, dtype=np.half), but no improvment...

>>NUMPY >>([inf, inf, inf], [1.0996, 2.1992, 3.3008], [1.0996, 2.1992, 3.3008]) for 27.5570968929s.

>>PYTHON>>([1.100000000045252, 2.200000000090504, 3.3000000001880174], [1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]) for 1.80307082548s.

Comment: Are you sure? Because as you can see from my results, I saw a *huge* improvement. Using numpy 1.5.1 with Python 2.7.1 if that matters.

Comment: The bigger point here, though, is that your numpy arrays should be created/allocated once and reused as much as possible rather than recreated inside of computation functions. Memory allocation takes a long time too and should be considered in any algorithm--it's not just computation that limits program speed.

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out by others, your problem is the conversion from list to array. By using the appropriate `numpy` functions for that, you will beat Python. I modified the main part of your program:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
  _t = time.clock()
  vertices_np = np.resize(np.array([ 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4 ], dtype=np.float64), 
                          (1000000, 4, 4))
  print "Creating numpy vertices: {}".format(time.clock() - _t)
  _t = time.clock()
  vertices=[[[1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4]]*4]*1000000
  print "Creating python vertices: {}".format(time.clock() - _t)
  _t=time.clock()
  print ">>NUMPY >>{} for {}s.".format(Fnumpy(vertices_np),time.clock()-_t)
  _t=time.clock()
  print ">>PYTHON>>{} for {}s.".format(Fpython(vertices),time.clock()-_t)
```

Running your code with the modifed main part results on my machine in:

```
Creating numpy vertices: 0.6
Creating python vertices: 0.01
>>NUMPY >>([1.1000000000452519, 2.2000000000905038, 3.3000000001880174], 
[1.1000000000000001, 2.2000000000000002, 3.2999999999999998], [1.1000000000000001, 
2.2000000000000002, 3.2999999999999998]) for 0.5s.
>>PYTHON>>([1.100000000045252, 2.200000000090504, 3.3000000001880174], [1.1, 2.2, 3.3], 
[1.1, 2.2, 3.3]) for 1.91s.
```

Although the array creation is still somewhat longer with Numpy tools as the creation of the nested lists with python's list multiplication operator (0.6s versus 0.01s), you gain a factor of ca. 4 for the run-time relevant part of your code. If I replace the line:

```
np_vertices=np.array(vertices)
```

with

```
np_vertices = np.asarray(vertices)
```

to avoid the copying of a big array, the running time of the numpy function even goes down to 0.37s on my machine, being more than 5 times faster then the pure python version.

In your real code, if you know the number of vertices in advance, you can preallocate the appropriate array via `np.empty()`, then fill it with the appropriate data, and pass it to the numpy-version of your function.