# Timeit showing that regular python is faster than numpy?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, timeit

I'm working on a piece of code for a game that calculates the distances between all the objects on the screen using their in-game coordinate positions. Originally I was going to use basic Python and lists to do this, but since the number of distances that will need calculated will increase exponentially with the number of objects, I thought it might be faster to do it with `numpy`.

I'm not very familiar with `numpy`, and I've been experimenting on basic bits of code with it.  I wrote a little bit of code to time how long it takes for the same function to complete a calculation in `numpy` and in regular Python, and `numpy` seems to consistently take a good bit more time than the regular python.

The function is very simple. It starts with 1.1 and then increments 200,000 times, adding 0.1 to the last value and then finding the square root of the new value.  It's not what I'll actually be doing in the game code, which will involve finding total distance vectors from position coordinates; it's just a quick test I threw together.  I already read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026519/pure-python-faster-than-numpy-can-i-make-this-numpy-code-faster) that the initialization of arrays takes more time in NumPy, so I moved the initializations of both the `numpy` and python arrays outside their functions, but Python is still faster than `numpy`.

Here is the bit of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import numpy
from timeit import timeit
#from time import process_time as timer
import math

thing = numpy.array([1.1,0.0], dtype='float')
thing2 = [1.1,0.0]

def NPFunc():

    for x in range(1,200000):
        thing[0] += 0.1
        thing[1] = numpy.sqrt(thing[0])


    print(thing)
    return None


def PyFunc():

    for x in range(1,200000):
        thing2[0] += 0.1
        thing2[1] = math.sqrt(thing2[0])

    print(thing2)
    return None


print(timeit(NPFunc, number=1))
print(timeit(PyFunc, number=1))
```

It gives this result, which indicates normal Python is 3x faster:

```
[ 20000.99999999    141.42489173]
0.2917748889885843

[20000.99999998944, 141.42489172698504]
0.10341173503547907
```

Am I doing something wrong, is is this calculation just so simple that it isn't a good test for `numpy`?

Comment: As a side note, doing a `print` inside something you plan to `timeit` is usually a bad idea. The time it takes to `print` something is highly variable—and can be longer than the time for the real work, too. In this case, it probably doesn't matter much, since you're using `number=1` and doing a lot of work inside the function, but it would still be better to get rid of the `print` calls.

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: Also, instead of looping 200000 times inside the function and using `number=1`, better to let `timeit` control at least some of that—e.g., loop 2000 times and us `number=100`. That gives it more to work with. But again, I doubt it would make much difference in this particular case.

Comment: One last thing: Replacing your lists with arrays and your loops with array functions gives you a constant-factor speedup. It may be an impressive speedup, like 6x or even 60x, but if your problem is exponential growth, that will probably only let you increase your maximum feasible N by 1 or 2…

Comment: Numpy is good at vectorized commands. Simple loops can usually gain a factor 100-1000 by using Compilers (Numba or Cython).

Answer (score 5):

> Am I doing something wrong, is is this calculation just so simple that it isn't a good test for NumPy?

It's not really that the calculation is simple, but that you're not taking any advantage of NumPy.

The main benefit of NumPy is vectorization: you can apply an operation to every element of an array in one go, and whatever looping is needed happens inside some tightly-optimized C (or Fortran or C++ or whatever) loop inside NumPy, rather than in a slow generic Python iteration.

But you're only accessing a single value, so there's no looping to be done in C.

On top of that, because the values in an array are stored as "native" values, NumPy functions don't need to unbox them, pulling the raw C `double` out of a Python `float`, and then re-box them in a new Python `float`, the way any Python math functions have to.

But you're not doing that either. In fact, you're *doubling* that work: You're pulling the value out o the array as a `float` (boxing it), then passing it to a function (which has to unbox it, and then rebox it to return a result), then storing it back in an array (unboxing it again).

And meanwhile, because `np.sqrt` is designed to work on arrays, it has to first check the type of what you're passing it and decide whether it needs to loop over an array or unbox and rebox a single value or whatever, while `math.sqrt` just takes a single value. When you call `np.sqrt` on an array of 200000 elements, the added cost of that type switch is negligible, but when you're doing it every time through the inner loop, that's a different story.

---

So, it's not an unfair test.

You've demonstrated that using NumPy to pull out values one at a time, act on them one at a time, and store them back in the array one at a time is slower than just not using NumPy.

But, if you compare it to actually taking advantage of NumPy—e.g., by creating an array of 200000 floats and then calling `np.sqrt` on that array vs. looping over it and calling `math.sqrt` on each one—you'll demonstrate that using NumPy the way it was intended is *faster* than not using it.

Comment: That makes sense.  I tried the lines of code Joran Beasley commented above it is significantly faster.  So the trick is to create/load values into numpy arrays as few times as possible but to make those arrays as large as you can?  This way once you begin doing operations on an array the program can efficiently progress through one large array without having to start and stop?

Comment: @CMB Exactly. Many problems can be turned into a sequence of elementwise (or otherwise array-at-a-time) operations, so if you can write them in terms of NumPy arrays, you get a big speedup. Some problems can't be written that way, so you get nothing but overhead from NumPy. (Except that you still get _space_ benefits over, say, a giant list of float objects—and for huge data, that can in turn save lots of time in allocation, cache, swapping, etc. But, on the other hand, sometimes you can write the non-NumPy code lazily so it takes no space at all, which is even better.)

Comment: So how beneficial is the calculation increase vs the time it takes to load normal python values into the array?  For the real code, each object in the game will be a class instance that contains its own position vector.  All of the objects would be stored in a list.  My original plan was to have a block of code go down that list and find the distance from each listed object to all the other objects.  Would it likely be faster or slower to transfer all those positions to a NumPy array and then perform the calculations?

Comment: @CMB If you have lots of those objects, it will probably be faster to store all those position vectors in a big 2D array, and have the class instances just keep track of their row index—or a reference to the row within the array—instead of holding the vector directly. However, it depends on what else you have to do with the instances. If you need to loop over all the instances in some time-critical part of your code, pulling just one piece of that loop out to an array operation on the side probably won't do much good; you need to move _everything_ to array ops to get a big speedup.

Comment: Does it make any difference to move values from NumPy arrays to other NumPy arrays?  Ie, if I stored the positions in their respective class instances as NumPy arrays, would it be easier to transfer them to a larger array, or would that just add more work?

Comment: @CMB Copying small arrays into a big array should save a bit of time over copying individual values into a big array, but if we're talking about a vector as an array of 3 or 4 values, doing that a few thousand times is not going to be a huge win. However, one of the other benefits of NumPy is that slicing arrays gives you another view on the same memory—so each instance could hold a row out of the big array, rather than holding an independent array, and then you don't have to copy anything around anywhere.

Comment: Object oriented design doesn't mesh well with `numpy` arrays.  Many small objects that 'know' how how to do specialized calculations (e.g. distance from each other) can't take advantage of the compiled code of arrays.  I imagine a table with many rows and just a few columns.  Objects with position vectors are a row oriented view, arrays are a column view, each array being one attribute across all objects.

Answer (score 3):

you're comparing it wrong

```
a_list = np.arange(0,20000,0.1)
timeit(lambda:np.sqrt(a_list),number=1)
```